# Grid loading too slow with out pagination

Tags: asp.net

We have developed Asp.net web application. and we are using asp.net gridview to display the records and edit.

here we have 5000 rows and 23 columns in single grid. it is taking long time for binding. our client refuse the pagination option. how to make the binding faster with 5000 to 7000 records.

Please Advise.

Thanks

Mayil.M

Comment: use multithreading.It will reduce the time to 75%.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your data come from? Is it database or other external resource?

You can use caching so you don't load the whole dataset from the external resource but from the memory. Please note this solution will not work if your data changes often.

Another approach would be to use some kind of partial loading mechanism using for example Ajax. This will however require changing approach as I am not sure the grid view control supports this. You would have to create custom control and then make sequential requests (using for example Ajax) for smaller chunks (eg. 200 records) of data and display them. Eventually you will have complete set but the data will be available faster.

Finally you can combine both, to make it even faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own paging mechanism. The problem is that DataBind retrieves all 7000 records (although only i.e. 20 is displayed/rendered). Create for example a stored procedure that will fetch only selected range of records (if you are on Page 2 you need to display only record id > 20 and <= 40 - considering that your pagesize is 20). Use SQL server CTE to get the row number (on SQL Server side) and features like BETWEEN. This stored procedure would return only those records which you really need to. Then change your grid view to get the data from this stored procedure.

Comment: Correct!! But _client refuse the pagination option_ (already mentioned in the question).

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. You don't show all 7000 records on single page so you need paging mechanism. If user doesn't use paging then fine but important is to NOT load all 7000 records and that's what I have written above. This is the key. You need the data source to already have only desired i.e. 20 records..

Answer (score 0):

You can load data on scroll like facebook wall.